# Would it be better to have 2 inbound channel adapters or 2 queue names on 1 inbound channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

My application is listening to 2 completely different queues. One queue will have thousands of messages come through it per minute (lets call it q.notifications) and the other will see something like 10 per day (lets call it q.subscriptionUpdates).

Would it be advantageous to create 2 `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter />` instances or would it still be better to add both queue names to the same one then have a header value router send the messages where they need to go?

Are there benefits to only having 1 adapter or does having 2 give me an edge?
Does having two adapters create a lot of unnecessary overhead? Am I over-thinking this and it really doesn't matter???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest it doesn't matter.

I'm sure both your adapters will rely on the same `ConnectionFactory` and since the real message consumption is done from the `Channel`s thread (`Channel.basicConsume`)from the `ConnectionFactory` anyway.

However it maybe would be better to have separate adapters, because they may consume from their own `Channel`s and there won't be need for extra `router` component.